# Multisegmented SMS causes Ublox to return CMS ERROR: 100

Tags: sms, at-command, modem

I'm using TOBY-L2 series (L210) Ublox module in the device.
I'm trying to send a multi-segmented SMS (800 bytes) and after few segments are sent (3 * 160 bytes) it gives me `CMS ERROR: 100`. Code: 100 is 'unknown' according to the specs, so it's not specific.

Note:
Modem is registered in 3G with the service provider.

Next AT commands don't respond and I cannot send the rest of the SMS segments out. I'm attaching the complete AT log that I use to communicate.

Please help me on the following

1. Why do I receive such error?
2. How to recothe modem from this error and proceed with the rest of the communication OR is there a way to prevent this situation?

**AT log (sent and received)**

```
AT+CFUN=15
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
OK
AT+CPIN?
+CME ERROR: 100
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY
OK
+CREG: 4
+UREG: 0
+CIEV: 9,1
+CIEV: 9,1
+CIEV: 12,2
+CREG: 0
+CIEV: 9,1
+CIEV: 12,1
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY
OK
ATE0
OK
AT+CREG=1
OK
AT+CMEE=1
OK
AT+CMER=1,0,0,2,1
OK
AT+CTZU=1
+CREG: 0
AT+UREG=1
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,0
OK
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,0
OK
AT+CGSN
354455181246191
OK
AT+CGMR
15.63
OK
AT+CCID
+CCID: 34560181111123406763
OK
AT+CNMI=1,1
OK
AT+CMGL=4
OK
AT+CFUN=1
+CIEV: 2,4
+CIEV: 8,0
+CIEV: 5,0
+CIEV: 8,0
+CIEV: 5,0
+CIEV: 8,0
+CIEV: 5,0
+CIEV: 8,0
+CIEV: 5,0
OK
+CIEV: 2,2
+CREG: 0
+CREG: 1
+CIEV: 3,1
AT+UDOPN=4
+UDOPN: 2,"ABCD Mobile"
OK
AT+UDOPN=0
+UDOPN: 0,"500:002"
OK
AT+COPS=2
+CIEV: 9,2
OK
+CREG: 0
+CIEV: 3,0
+UREG: 0
+CIEV: 9,1
AT+URAT=2
OK
OK
AT+COPS=0
OK
+CREG: 2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CREG: 1
+CIEV: 3,1
+UREG: 3
+CIEV: 9,2
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1
OK
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,3
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1
OK
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,3
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1
OK
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,3
OK
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1
OK
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,3
OK
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1
OK
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,3
OK
AT+CCLK?
+CCLK: "17/02/13,15:54:39+44"
OK
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1
OK
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
AT+UREG?
+UREG: 1,3
OK
+CIEV: 2,3
+CIEV: 2,2
AT+CMGS=154
>
00D1000B911654219561F10000FFA005000324060162B219AD66BBE17230574C36A3D56C375C0EE68A8162B219AD66BBE17230574C36A3D56C375C0EE68A8162B219AD66BBE17230574C36A3D56C375C0EE68A8162B219AD66BBE17230574C36A3D56C375C0EE68A8162B219AD66BBE17230574C36A3D56C375C0EE68A8162B219AD66BBE17230574C36A3D56C375C0EE68A8162B219AD66BBE172▒
+CMGS: 175
OK
AT+CMGS=154
>
00D1000B911654219561F10000FFA005000324060260AE986C46ABD96EB81CCC1503C564335ACD76C3E560AE986C46ABD96EB81CCC1503C564335ACD76C3E560AE986C46ABD96EB81CCC1503C564335ACD76C3E560AE986C46ABD96EB81CCC1503C564335ACD76C3E560AE986C46ABD96EB81CCC1503C564335ACD76C3E560AE986C46ABD96EB81CCC1503C564335ACD76C3E560AE986C46ABD96E▒
+CMGS: 176
OK
AT+CMGS=154
>
00D1000B911654219561F10000FFA00500032406037039982B068AC966B49AED86CBC15C31D98C56B3DD7039982B068AC966B49AED86CBC15C31D98C56B3DD7039982B068AC966B49AED86CBC15C31D98C56B3DD7039982B068AC966B49AED86CBC15C31D98C56B3DD7039982B068AC966B49AED86CBC15C31D98C56B3DD7039982B068AC966B49AED86CBC15C31D98C56B3DD7039982B068AC966▒
+CMS ERROR: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" we found was to use `AT+CMMS=1;+CGMS=<len>` for all but the last message (use just `AT+CGMS=<len>` there), and add a 10 second delay between each message.

I've reported the issue to Ublox, so maybe they'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks Aldrian. I also reported this to UBlox and they requested debug logs. We had to do some alterations to h/w and capture output from some of the gpios. Hope they will use that information and fix it. +1 for reporting the same :)

Comment: The issue is fixed in the latest firmware for us (A01.50 for L210)

Comment: Good to hear that it is fixed :)